# Find equation given sequence of points

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a general mathematical procedure that given a sequence of (x,y) points forming a straight or curved line (e.g. see pic), it produces its corresponding equation? If this does not exist can someone point me in the right direction on how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can start from here:

1. [Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation)
2. [Linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression)
3. [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)
4. [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series)